# ASP.NET URL rewrite rule that ignores AJAX requests

Tags: asp.net, ajax, iis, url-rewriting

How would I go about creating a URL rewrite rule that enforces lower case URLs except when the request is an AJAX request, that is when the header X-Requested-With has the value of XMLHttpRequest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out.

```
        <rule name="LowerCaseURL" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="[A-Z]" ignoreCase="false" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                <add input="{HTTP_X_Requested_With}" pattern="^XMLHttpRequest$" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="{ToLower:{URL}}" />
        </rule>
```